# How to used an attribute in a SqlDataReader context ?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, sqldatareader

I'm trying to buid a generic SQL executor.

It's working if my DTO class attributes have the same name than my SQL table column.

To increase the generic part of my code, I add an attribute to my DTO in order to separate my DTO attribute to SQL column.

But it's not working

my DTO class :

```
public class CarModels
{
    [DbColumn("ca_id")] //column name
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DbColumn("ca_label")]  //column name
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

my generic method :

```
    public List<T> ExecuteSQLSELECTCommand<T>(string SQLcommand) where T : new()
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> databaseMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>(); ;

        Get_Connection();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(SQLcommand);
            List<T> res = new List<T>();
            try
            {
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                 while (reader.Read())
                  {
                    T t = new T();

                    for (int inc = 0; inc < reader.FieldCount; inc++)
                    {   

                            Type type = t.GetType();
                         //how to get attribute link to current FiedCount ? 
                            PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(reader.GetName(inc));
                            prop.SetValue(t, reader.GetValue(inc), null);                  

                    }
                    res.Add(t);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

and my call :

```
List<CarModels> carTest = db.ExecuteSQLCommand<CarModels>("SELECT ca_id, ca_label from cartracker.ca_cars");
```

my question, how can I recover value of the attribute in order to build a PropertyInfo in a MySqlDataReader context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class like this.  Can you please tell me if it helps:

```
public class AnEntity<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T AnEntity(string[] token, ref int i, out TokenEnum tokenEnum,
                                        out string tokenException)
    {
       ...
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        try
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                ...
                    if (property.Name == "AName") 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
...
```